# Devexpress gridview Duplicate values not accepted in gridview

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, devexpress, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am using an devexpress gridview to load data and then insert it into the database and I want to prevent duplicate data from gridview .

```
int rowHandle = gvSaleDetail.GetRowHandle(gvSaleDetail.DataRowCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
            {
                string cod = txtcode.text
                            //What should I write in the query?
                if (cod that it already exists in gridview)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The code already exists");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

iam try this and working its make filer by gvSaleDetail.Columns["Code"]

```
        // check if item added into gvSaleDetail.

        GridColumn item= gvSaleDetail.Columns["Code"];

        item.FilterInfo = new ColumnFilterInfo("[Code] ="+txttest.Text);

        // if item alredy added in gvSaleDetail.

        if(gvSaleDetail.RowCount != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("item alredy added in gridview");
        }
         // if item not in gvSaleDetail.
        else
        {
            // create action
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).